# Install Ubuntu using serial port

Tags: system-installation, serial-port

I have a set of 6 computers (3 embedded computers and 3 SBCs) without graphical output. Each have a serial port. I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Server.

When I try to boot using ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso, I have the following output

```
graphics initialization failed
Error setting up gfxboot
boot:
Loading bootlogo...

Initializing gfx code..
graphics initialization failed
Error setting up gfxboot
boot:
Loading bootlogo...

Initializing gfx code..
graphics initialization failed
Error setting up gfxboot
boot:
Loading bootlogo...

Initializing gfx code..
graphics initialization failed
Error setting up gfxboot
boot:
Loading bootlogo...

Initializing gfx code..
graphics initialization failed
Error setting up gfxboot
boot:
Loading bootlogo...

Initializing gfx code..
graphics initialization failed
Error setting up gfxboot
boot:
Loading bootlogo...

Initializing gfx code..
graphics initialization failed
Error setting up gfxboot
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
Could not allocate memory.
boot:
```

Comment: Live Server and Live Desktop installers *require* a graphical display, so I think you're using the wrong installer for your needs. Can you use an SD card? Netboot? Chroot?

Comment: I assumed so, but I didn't see any other installer for Ubuntu, and I know it used to be possible (for 16.04 at least). There is no SD card. Netboot looks difficult because the documentation for Ubuntu 20.04 is outdated and things changed a lot lately with dnsmasq. I don't know what is a chroot install.

Comment: Could I "dd" an .img to the drive using Tiny Core Linux?

Comment: If there is an .img that matches your board's architecture, then you can certainly try. However, that makes you a tester...if it bricks we're sorry but won't replace it. Take a look at this older, safer method that we do support: [Chroot + debootstrap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebootstrapChroot). It works over a serial port. Try it in a VM first, of course.

Comment: I couldn't find a method to do chroot + debotstrap over serial port. I'm probably missing something

Answer (score 1):

At the `boot:` prompt type `live initrd=initrd.gz console=ttyS0,115200` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This will boot the Ubuntu 20.04 installation process over the `ttyS0` serial port.